# Determine if user is typing character by character or if more than 1 character is entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I need to determine if a user is typing character by character into a text field or using browser autocomplete / pasting more than 1 character in javascript / jQuery.

I need to use the input method to determine the browser autocomplete:

```
$('input[type=text]').input(function(){
  var a = this.value; // input value
  var b = a.length; // amount of chars

  $.each(a, function(i, j) { 
    // Loop through the input value each time after something is entered
  }
});
```

I think I need the length of the last input value, so if it's = 1 typing is assumed or if it's more than 1 pasting / autocomplete is assumed.

Technically, 1 character can be pasted but no need to worry about that for now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to handle the `keyup` event and track the length of the input string between the current `keyup` and the prior. If the difference in the string's `length` is greater than `1`, then you know it was either the result of the auto-complete or pasted input.

Comment: I have tried some stuff with keyup, but problem is keyup is not triggered when the user clicks on an autofill suggestion which is then pasted in the text field. I can bind keyup and input but the problem with that is they are both triggered when typing and only input is triggered with autocomplete.

Comment: ahh yes, that's true. then, handle that event as well (if the autocomplete broadcasts an event, handle it, else, handle it's click) and execute the method i described above. you may also want to handle the right-click (when the target is the input field), as that is likely another caveat.

Comment: jquery allows you to assign a handler to multiple events in a succinct manner ... `$('input[type="text"]').on('click, keyup, someotherevent', handlerFunction);` where the handler function is used to determine what to do with said input and whether or not the input difference between the current and prior execution is greater than `1` ...